# Error While Sending Mail using node.js in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2

```
{
  message: 'Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: xxx@gmai.com, xxx@gmail.com',
  code: 'MessageRejected',
  time: Tue Sep 12 2017 13:01:12 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  requestId: '73dddb05-97ba-11e7-9847-c5dd9b1b6fa5',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 94.04094410128891
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may send email to only verified emails using AWS SES. To add email id to the verified email list, add email using SES (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#verified-senders-email:) and click to verification email send by AWS. After that you may able to send email using AWS SES.

Also, you need to add IAM role to the lambda to get access of SES.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If SES is requiring you to verify email addresses that you can send to, then you haven't taken your AWS SES account out of sandbox mode. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to request that Amazon support take your SES account out of [sandbox mode](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html). Until you do that you will only be able to send emails to verified email addresses.